# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found when creating shell scripts

Tags: python, typeerror, python-2.6

I am creating a python script which dividing a big sh file into small sh files, then sends every sh file into a new screen. I tried this code

```
import os

splitLen = 2         # 2 lines per file
outputBase = 'US11_'
# This is shorthand and not friendly with memory
# on very large files (Sean Cavanagh), but it works.
input = open('US11.sh', 'r').read().split('\n')
at = 1
for lines in range(0, len(input), splitLen):
    # First, get the list slice
    outputData = input[lines:lines+splitLen]

    # Now open the output file, join the new slice with newlines
    # and write it out. Then close the file.
    output = open(outputBase + str(at) + '.sh', 'w')
    output.write('#!/bin/sh\n')
    output.write('\n'.join(outputData))
    output.write('\n')
    output.close()
    os.chmod('{}'.format(output), 0o777)
    os.system("screen -m -d bash -c ./" + output)    
    # Increment the counter
    at += 1
```

but when executing the python file , this error showed up

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

Now the process should write the split lines into the sh file then give the sh file the permissions and send the sh file to a screen to be executed . after that complete the process at the same phase for all the files .

What is the error in my code ? any idea ?

Comment: Please do include the **full traceback** of the error, so we don't have to guess at what line might have caused it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry. I hit Enter and the comment was posted incomplete. It was the same code as in your answer!

Answer (score 1):

`os.chmod()` takes a filename, but you are trying to pass in the file object instead.

You could use `output.name` here:

```
os.chmod(output.name, 0o777)
os.system("screen -m -d bash -c ./" + output.name)
```

or you could first store the filename you generate in a variable:

```
filename = '{0}{1}.sh'.format(outputBase, at)
with open(filename, 'w') as output:
    output.write('#!/bin/sh\n')
    output.write('\n'.join(outputData))
    output.write('\n')
os.chmod(filename, 0o777)
os.system("screen -m -d bash -c ./{0}".format(filename))
```

I also used the file object as a context manager here; the `with` statement closes the file for you when the block exits.

Comment: Hi, This error showed up

  File "1.py", line 20, in <module>
    os.chmod('{}'.format(output.name), 0o777)
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: @abualameer94: you are using Python 2.6 then, I presume. I'll update.